# How 2 WebAPI Routing can accept same type parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a web Api that has several methods. I have problem with routing. I have 1 method that is returning products by `yearId` and another method that is returning product by `product id`. Here are 2 routes I came up with:

```
   /api/records/products?yearId=10

   /api/records/products/15
```

These are my 2 methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getbyyearid")]
    public async Task<Product> GetByYearid(int yearId)
    {
          .....     
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getbyid")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetByid(int productId)
    {
        ......
    }
```

what route mapping should I have so I can access my Web API with these 2 routes:

```
    /api/records/products?yearId=10

    /api/records/products/15
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)  to customize how you want the routes to be used.

Here is an example of how you can achieve the routes you wanted:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/records")]
public class RecordsController: ApiController {
    // GET api/records/products?yearid=10    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("products")]
    public async Task<Product> GetByYearid(int yearId) {
          .....     
    }

    // GET api/records/products/15
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("products/{productId:int}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetByid(int productId) {
        ......
    }
}
```